# Is it normal for Vercel to initiate a build even if there's a push to the `develop` branch, which is not the production branch?

Tags: vercel

To reproduce the problem:

1. I have a project with `main`, `develop`, and other task branches.
2. I deploy the project on Vercel. By default, Vercel looks for the `main` branch.
3. When the app was deployed, I temporarily changed the `develop` branch to serve as the production branch. However, even though I made this change, when a push was made to the remote repository, there was no build on Vercel's side. I tried multiple times, but nothing happened. Only changes made to `main` triggered a new build.
4. I spent a couple of hours reading Vercel's documentation and other resources, but I couldn't find anything specific to address my issue.
5. Eventually, I merged `develop` into `main` and adjusted the settings in Vercel, designating back `main` as the production branch.
   6 . A few hours later, any pushes made from `develop`, as well as from `main`, triggered a build on Vercel. I became concerned and started to wonder if there might be something wrong with Git under the hood. In fact, I even created a new repository on GitHub, initialized a fresh Next.js project with new Git files, and uploaded it to Vercel, but I encountered the same problem.

Can anyone explain what's happening? Is it normal for Vercel to initiate a build even if there's a push to the `develop` branch, which is not the production branch?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You see one's a [preview](https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/preview-deployments) build, right?

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't see it. What's that 'Preview' is supposed to do? Although I didn't pay attention to the word itself, it looked like a typical build.